# How to configure Spring HATEOAS behind proxy?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I have Spring Data Rest with Hateoas as my backed. It is behind a proxy.

Backend url: `backend.com`

Proxy url: `proxy.com`

When I query proxy url, e.g. `http://proxy.com/items/1`, I get a response with `href` links with domain `backend.com`. I need the domain to be `proxy.com`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure your proxy is adding `X-Forwarded-Host: proxy.com` header to the **request** that is passed to `backend.com`. Then Spring Hateoas will automatically generate link hrefs with `proxy.com`.

`X-Forwarded-Host` can contain port.

Also see [other X-Forwarded-* headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), which are supported too.

Comment: Hi, I also want to implement same thing in my REST API. I tried to set IP of my proxy server but its giving me "NumberFormatException".  See the exception: 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "  192.168.1.1"

Comment: Hi, can you show me the line of code where you try to set `X-Forwarded-Host` header?

Answer (score 33):

As of Spring-Boot 2.1 / Spring 5.1, Spring shifts the responsibility of handling X-Forwarded-* from Spring HATEOAS to Spring MVC.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16668

You now require the registration of a filter bean.

Minimal implementation:

```
@Bean
FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> forwardedHeaderFilter()
{
    FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    bean.setFilter(new ForwardedHeaderFilter());
    return bean;
}
```

Comment: If you use Spring HATEOAS and Spring Boot, there seems to be a parameter for that: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/753#issuecomment-463077217 :     If the proxy adds conventional X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto headers (most proxy servers do so), the absolute links should be rendered correctly, provided server.use-forward-headers is set to true in your application.properties.

Comment: On AWS using a load balancer and cloudfront, the combination of server.use-forward-headers=true in application.properties and a lambda that sets the host and the proto for the Forwareded header and that is configured in Cloudfront as origin request does the trick

Comment: Hi, this was working fine until I add Spring Cloud Gateway as a proxy. After adding the gateway, now the HATEOAS links are rplaced to `http` from `https`.
On gateway, tried `forward-headers-strategy: framework/native` and `ForwardedHeaderTransformer` Bean, but nothing is working. Any suggestions to make it working?

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by the comment from Cyril Gambis, Spring offers a property `server.use-forward-headers`, which exists at least from 1.3.0.RELEASE. From Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE, that property is deprecated, use `server.forward-headers-strategy` instead.

When you use Spring Data Rest, I suggest set `server.forward-headers-strategy = framework`, then Spring Hatoaes generates the proxied URI for href with the help of `x-forwarded-*` headers.

## Reference

- [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-behind-a-proxy-server)
- [Spring Hateoas Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/1.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#server.link-builder.forwarded-headers)

Answer (score 2):

Though this has been answered by Mariano, I wanted to add that it works for Spring Boot. However, if you don't use Spring Boot and instead use Spring 5.1.X in a traditional web application deployed within J2EE container (like mine), you will need to add a filter to your web application's web.xml similar to below:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>forwardedHeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.ForwardedHeaderFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>relativeRedirects</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>forwardedHeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Besides this, you will also need to upgrade Hateoas to version 0.25.1 where this issue has been fixed from Hateoas side.