# Force spring data rest to use https scheme

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I’m using [spring-data-rest](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) in my application which is behind apache reverse proxy that redirects from HTTP to HTTPS

This in turn leads to wrong hrefs: `http` instead `https` scheme.

**Example:**

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://my.host/api/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can configure `spring.data.rest` to force use https scheme?

Comment: It is unclear how you produce your links. Anyway, keep in mind that proxypass(reverse) works on HTTP protocol headers, so it doesn't have anything to do with the protocol you use in your webapp. So probably there is nothing to setup, other than check Apache proxypass configuration, or check your webapp or - hugh - your Tomcat config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging in the source code, I found out that all link creations originates from this [point](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/ServletUriComponentsBuilder.java#L188) and it seems to be impossible to configure forced use of https scheme in a 'standard' way.

So I created a filter that replaces `http://` to `https://` in request URL and the problem has gone. Here is the snippet:

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        final HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapped = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
            @Override
            public StringBuffer getRequestURL() {
                final StringBuffer originalUrl = ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getRequestURL();
                final String updatedUrl = originalUrl.toString().replace("http://", "https://");
                return new StringBuffer(updatedUrl);
            }
        };
        filterChain.doFilter(wrapped, servletResponse);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little bit not sure but. I did following and it seems links work.

```
server:
  forward-headers-strategy: NATIVE
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and it is all the answers those helped me to find a simple solution in 2 steps :

1. I added configuration in my `spring-data-rest v2.5.4` application to use `X-Forwarded-*` headers

   ```java
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import org.springframework.web.filter.ForwardedHeaderFilter;


   @Configuration()
   public class ApiConfiguration {

     @Bean()
     ForwardedHeaderFilter forwardedHeaderFilter() {
       return new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
     }
   }
   ```
2. I added comfiguration to my proxy (`nginx v1.20.0`) to forward `scheme`, `host` and `port`

   ```sh
   location /api {
     proxy_pass       http://localhost:8080;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
   }
   ```

Hope that it will help next ones

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Spring Data Rest uses HATEOAS which support special headers from proxy requests, check this out:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/107
- [How to configure Spring HATEOAS behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020188/how-to-configure-spring-hateoas-behind-proxy)

The header you are looking for is: `X-Forwarded-Proto`