# Jersey JAX-RS HATEOAS behind proxy

Tags: java, web-services, rest, proxy, jax-rs

**Note**: Please do not mark this question as a duplicate of [How to configure Spring HATEOAS behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020188/how-to-configure-spring-hateoas-behind-proxy), this question talks about JAX-RS, not Spring.

I have a proxy with ExpressJS, and a REST API using Jersey.
I also have HATEOAS in my endpoints.

In the responses, instead of having `proxy.com` as the URL, I am getting `backend.com`.

Like in [How to configure Spring HATEOAS behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020188/how-to-configure-spring-hateoas-behind-proxy), I've added the `X-Forwarded-Host` header but still no success.

Comment: What are you using for your web server? Is it Jetty / Netty / tomcat / ... ?

Comment: Spring boot so it is Tomcat

Comment: Isn't nobody going to help me? ;(